# Should a user logged in through Facebook be able to delete their account?

Tags: facebook, accounts

In my app I give the option the users of logging in with their Facebook account for convenience. Every modern app gives its users the option of deleting/disabling their account. The question is whether I should provide such an option to the users who logged in with Facebook.

Someone might ask why not, and say that it is the natural thing to do. I am asking, though, because I have not encountered on the web such an option in sites that use Facebook login. Probably I am mistaken.

Nonetheless, to be sure I wanted to ask this question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and as far as I understand your question): when you log in to a site, service or app using an existing account (name it facebook, google, etc.), you are not "creating" an account; you're linking this site/service/app with your existing account. That means deleting the account corresponds to the original site, not your site/service/app.

Mostly, what these sites allow you to do is to remove the link between your account and the site. This means you won't be able to log in using your existing credentials, not that these credentials will be disabled everywhere.

You don't have to go too far: StackExchange allows you to create an account or use existing credentials or both, and at any moment you can choose to remove the use of these existing credentials:

1. Go to your `Profile` page
2. Click on the `Edit Profile & Settings` link

[image: Edit Profile and Settings]

3. Click on the `My Logins` link

[image: My Logins]

Here you'll see the accounts you have linked to your SE network login, and you can choose wich to remove.

Comment: You said to look at the StackExchange example:from where I can remove the use of existing credentials....I can only find the logout link.

Comment: I edited my answer to show where you cand find it

Comment: thanks for the help....am I right to assume that removing the account(used for login) all my data will be permanently lost?Of course I do not want to lose my data....but I just want to know what happens afterwards...thanks.